# React Leaflet - TileLayer does not render when it is first loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

This is my first time using React-Leaflet. I am doing the same as shown in the [documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker), but the map is grayed out when the page is first loaded. However if i were to resize the browser, the map renders properly and shows map.

**index.js**

```js
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""
/>
```

**package.json**

```
"react-leaflet": "^3.0.2",
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
```

**css file**

```css
.leaflet-container {
    height: 310px;
    width: 440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**myComponent**

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

const Location = () => {
   return (
     <div className="location-container">
       <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "310px" }}
        center={[51.505, -0.09]}
        zoom={15}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
       >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
     </MapContainer>
   </div>
  );
};
export default Location;
```

i added leaflet-css to my index.js, i added width and height to my leaflet DOM. I noticed that when it is first loaded, the pictures are not coming from the api, but when I resize browser, the pictures come. Here are some pictures.

**first loaded**

[image: gray screen]

[image: images are not loaded]

**after resize the browser**

[image: map showing properly]
[image: images loaded properly]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map is not visible at initialization using react-leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59856361/map-is-not-visible-at-initialization-using-react-leaflet)

Comment: I couldn't find a way to add map.invalidateSize() to my component

Comment: have you tried `componentDidMount() { const map = this.mapRef.current.leafletElement; setTimeout(() => { map.invalidateSize(); }, 250); }` ?

Comment: yes, i tried. But i think i couldn't set mapRef properly. I use useRef hook. `const ref = useRef();` and add ref to  `<div ref={ref} className="location-container"></div>` then. `useEffect(() => { const map = ref.current.leafletElement; setTimeout(() => {map.invalidateSize();  }, 250); }, []);` but it gives an error and say invalidateSize is not a function

Comment: Okey then I can't help you, because I'm not a react programmer, sorry

Comment: Most probably the `ref` must be set on the `<MapContainer>` element, not on its wrapper div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I write if anyone faced the same problem.

I looked through the [documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map#usemap) of the react-leaflet and found this in the section on react-hooks. I added **useMap** to access map functions in React-leaflet.

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, useMap } from "react-leaflet";
```

Then, I created a new component on the same page.

```
const ResizeMap = () => {
  const map = useMap();
  map._onResize();
  return null;
};
```

Here I called the _onResize method. Thus, when the page is first loaded, it resizes the location of the map and the images are loaded properly. On the other projects they solved this with `map.invalidateSize();`

I used the resize component here. It has to be inside the MapContainer.

```
     <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "310px" }}
        center={[51.505, -0.09]}
        zoom={15}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
      >
        <ResizeMap />
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
```